# Packages-lock.json doesn't contain SDK which needs upgrade

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play

Uploading app to google play I'm getting this message from google:

> "app X version code 19 includes includes SDK com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads
> or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects
> personal... According to your SDK provider, you may consider upgrading
> to 4.0.1, and/or contacting your SDK provider to see if a suitable
> later version might be available. Google is unable to endorse or
> recommend any third party software.
> ACTION REQUIRED: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the noncompliant version.
> "

I dont see in my packages-lock.json file any unity-ads but I still get this message.

Also the version I'm uploading now is greater then 19. So I think I need to deactivate the older versions? Where do I do it? I can't find it.

Comment: Do not look in the lock file but the [manifest.json](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-manifestPrj.html) .. simply open the package manager and look if there is/are packages that can be updated

Comment: I looked at the manifest as well. it did not appear there. and the package is not installed in the packageManager. In fact I deleted it recently.
I now think it's related to an older version of my app bundle and trying to find where I deactivate older versions